# ¿Cómo busco el valor de un índice determinado en una lista de diccionarios?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy intentando comprobar si existe un valor en una lista. No controlo de Python y no consigo sacarlo. Esto es lo que tengo,

```
[{'nodo1': {'openfiles': [], 'resume': None, 'total': 0}},
 {'nodo2': {'openfiles': [{'file': 'file1',
                'id': 25159713,
                'locks': 0,
                'permissions': ['read'],
                'user': 'user-1'}],
 'resume': None,
 'total': 1}},
 {'nodo3': {'openfiles': [{'file': 'file1',
                'id': 42608352,
                'locks': 0,
                'permissions': [],
                'user': 'user-2'},
               {'file': 'file2',
                'id': 42608377,
                'locks': 0,
                'permissions': [],
                'user': 'user-3'}],
 'resume': None,
 'total': 6}}]
```

Necesito comprobar si existe el valor `file` y en caso de que así sea me devuelva los valores de ese objeto.

si hago esto llego a comprobar el valor "nodo" pero no consigo llega a file.

```
if nodo in result[0]:
```

En resumen, ¿como llegaria a comprobar el valor de file y recuperar ese objeto?

Comment: por favor dale [edit] y añade lo que intentaste exactamente, así como cuál debería ser la salida

Comment: dicho lo cual, siempre es bueno dar buen formato al JSON para que se vea bien lo que queremos buscar.